# The implementation of webrtc peerconnection state is inconsistent with the standard

Tags: webrtc

According to the [WebRTC 1.0: Real-time Communication Between Browsers](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnectionstate-failed), webrtc peerConnection state fails only when the previous state doesn't apply and any RTCIceTransports or RTCDtlsTransports are in the `failed` state.

But I logged iceConnectionState and dtls state when peerConnection state change to failed by wifi closed, and I found out that iceConnectionState is disconnected and dtls state is connected.

It's inconsistent with the description on [WebRTC 1.0: Real-time Communication Between Browsers](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnectionstate-failed)

Why is it inconsistent?

[image: error image]

Answer (score 2):

Yea that looks wrong to me!

I would file a bug with Chromium project https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: thanks! I also test it on safari and it's consistent on safari.

Comment: hi, sean! had you file bug on Chromium project? can you post the bug's url on here?

Comment: I looked and did not see a related bug on Chromium - if you are not filing one, i will go ahead and do so, This relates, AFAICT, to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421478/ice-connection-state-fail-indication-with-peer-connection-state-fail-during-conn which i just asked about.